# How to make carousel slider on the left side

Tags: flutter, carousel, carousel-slider

i was new on programming and now i was learning by try design to coding from internet. And this the sample i want to create
[image: design i try to make]

i was try making that slider using carousel_slider, i can show it but i cant relocate the location of the slider ( carousel slider always on center )

[image: this is how my program run]

```
final List<Widget> myData = [
    Today_Widget(),
    Today_Widget(),
    Today_Widget(),
    Today_Widget(),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CarouselSlider(
      options: CarouselOptions(
        initialPage: 0,
        aspectRatio: 1,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        viewportFraction: 0.65,
        enableInfiniteScroll: false,
      ),
      items: myData,
    );
```

```
return Container(
      width: 350,
      height: 350,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(8),
          ),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/images_mainprofile_1.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: blackColor.withOpacity(0.2),
              blurRadius: 35,
              offset: Offset(0, 8),
            )
          ]),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 93,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              color: blackColor.withOpacity(0.60),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        'Ancala Coffe & Bistro',
                        style: title.copyWith(
                          fontWeight: semiBold,
                          fontSize: 14,
                          color: whiteColor,
                        ),
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 20,
                          height: 20,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image:
                                    AssetImage('assets/images/icon_star.png'),
                                fit: BoxFit.fill),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '4.4',
                          style: title.copyWith(
                            fontWeight: medium,
                            color: whiteColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Text(
                  'Cafe bergaya modern industrial di kawasan Batu, mempertemukan modernitas dengan alam. Selain kopi, cafe ini juga menyediakan tanaman hias dan pemandangan yang indah',
                  style: regularText.copyWith(color: whiteColor),
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  maxLines: 2,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

i already try using stack then positioned but i was fail, i try using column then cross/main axis alignment but it do nothing too and now i was at limit and stuck on that slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with `transform`.

```dart
Container(
  width: 350,
  height: 350,
  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(-350 / 8, 0, 0),
```

Note the logic is perfect here,  the `-350/8` is depended on aspect ratio.